# xml parsing using jsoup error

Tags: android, jsoup

I am stuck at parsing a xml file.
I have the following code of an activity:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(sb.toString(), "", Parser.xmlParser());

for (Element e : doc.select("Placemark")) {
    Log.d(TAG, "name is " + e.attr("name")+ "cordinates is" + e.attr("coordinates"));
```

I have this xml example:

```xml
<Placemark>
    <name>international route for military only</name>
    <styleUrl>#m_ylw-pushpin0</styleUrl>
    <LineString>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <coordinates>
            34.9524993959688,32.7730878314906,0 34.95166998854646,32.77308993256781,0 34.95125522754987,32.77309097997785,0 34.95070215058794,32.77309237599226,0 34.94918083131482,32.77309620394223,0 34.94752038951339,32.77309850484357,0 34.94655149233169,32.77309830859218,0 34.94572098730102,32.77309813906572,0 34.94502892287641,32.77309798764293,0 34.94419838488641,32.77309782117877,0 34.94309104377032,32.77309757681172,0 34.94226051634391,32.77309738973906,0 34.94115313434187,32.77309712978963,0 34.94018416814745,32.77309689649781,0 34.93935361177677,32.77309669003321,0 34.93866147471769,32.77309651419306,0 34.93769247332618,32.77309626314753,0 34.93658505149507,32.77309586239551,0 34.93533920626601,32.77309542577984,0 34.93450864230719,32.77309510022808,0 34.93340122016876,32.77309465949123,0 34.93160165271385,32.77309392217991,0 34.92883324477039,32.7728599214421,0 34.92385060482191,32.77169369268832,0 34.91540783742491,32.76947803887981,0 34.90793372651729,32.7673788666683,0 34.90322739422959,32.76621216804099,0 34.89893646854004,32.76481273889556,0 34.89533713275235,32.76387923817537,0 34.89339945743092,32.76306307317424,0 34.89215360021323,32.76271299419985,0 
        </coordinates>
    </LineString>
</Placemark>
```

I get the parsing correctly when I am printing the doc. But when I am trying to grab the name and coordinates of the placemark by accessing its attribute field, it gives me an empty string.

It seems when I use `doc.select("Placemark")`, it only takes the strings inside the tag and it ignores the tag itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `e.select("name").text()`

```
for (Element e : doc.select("Placemark")) { 
    Log.d(TAG, "name is " + e.select("name").text()+ "cordinates is" + e.select("coordinates").text()); 
}
```

Comment: Good luck. If my answer helped you, please accepting it.